# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 21013: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8

I was writing a dataframe to csv like this

```
df.to_csv('<op-loc>',sep='^',encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

This is the error i'm facing.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 21013: invalid continuation byte
```

I did try with `utf-8` and `latin-1` but still i'm facing the issue.

Comment: I recommend you to specify encoding while reading file and same encoding while writing to file. This might solve your problem.

Comment: I used this, while reading # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- , but with when i was writing with utf-8, it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried with `sep='\t'`?

Comment: No. I didn't try. But i need sep as hat(^).